# How to align multiple lines on same indent?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

Desired effect is this:

[image]

But my document is this:

[image]

my code:

```
From paragraph 1: \\
\textbf{Q1}\quad The writer calls the advertising industry ‘universal’. What phrase is used later in the paragraph to echo this idea? \hfill [1] \\ \\
From paragraph 2: \\
\textbf{Q2}\quad (a) How do we realise early in the paragraph that the writer does not regard advertisements as simply ways of \textquoteleft{}relaying necessary information\textquoteright{}? \hfill [1] \\ \\
(b) The cafe owner \textquoteleft{}might be tempted\textquoteright{} to add to his advertisement. What does he hope to achieve by doing this? \hfill [1] \\ \\
(c) Explain \textbf{in your own words} why the writer feels that the world of advertising is such a dangerous place for ordinary people. \hfill [2] \\ \\
\textbf{Q3}\quad Why do you think that the writer finds it surprising that advertising methods are similar throughout the world? \hfill [1] \\ \
```

Comment: Code example, please, that would doable with a normal enumerate

Comment: my code is simple - i do not know how to achieve that effect

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the help of the [enumitem](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package you can easily achieve what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\noindent
From paragraph 1:
\begin{enumerate}[label={\bfseries Q\arabic*},leftmargin=*]
  \item The writer calls the advertising industry ‘universal’. What phrase is used later in the paragraph to echo this idea? \hfill [1]
\end{enumerate}
From paragraph 2:
\begin{enumerate}[label={\bfseries Q\arabic*},resume,leftmargin=*]
  \item
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item How do we realise early in the paragraph that the writer does not regard advertisements as simply ways of \textquoteleft relaying necessary information\textquoteright ? \hfill [1]
    \item The cafe owner \textquoteleft might be tempted\textquoteright to add to his advertisement. What does he hope to achieve by doing this? \hfill [1]
    \item Explain \textbf{in your own words} why the writer feels that the world of advertising is such a dangerous place for ordinary people. \hfill [2]
  \end{enumerate}
  \item Why do you think that the writer finds it surprising that advertising methods are similar throughout the world? \hfill [1]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: this indents the items uniformly but i cant use the enumeration. my code consists of questions and answers

Comment: @umar why can't you use enumeration for questions?

Comment: my code is now given in question

Comment: @umar: I added a new example code.

Comment: excellent! but one problem: can an enumeration item continue on the next page? a long item of several lines is cutting through the footer and the end of the page!

Comment: @umar: sure, items admit page breaks. If you're having any problems, perhaps you should open a new question, including a MWE showing the undesired behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\item bla bla
\item bla bla
\item bla bla
\end{enumerate}
\item  bla bla
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: that does not produce the desired result. Replace "bla bla" with "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb" and you will see how it goes wrong.