# how to align multiple lines on same indent without enumeration?

Tags: indentation, paragraphs

I want a similar effect as desired in the question [How to align multiple lines on same indent?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13616/22491). But I don't want the enumeration or bullet point list. I want only more indentation for some lines like the following:

```
some text some text some text 
some text some text some text 
    some indented text some indented text some indented text 
    some indented text some indented text some indented text 
         some more indented text some more indented text  
         some more indented text some more indented text  
some text some text some text 
some text some text some text 
    some indented text some indented text some indented text 
    some indented text some indented text some indented text 
         some more indented text some more indented text  
         some more indented text some more indented text  
    some indented text some indented text some indented text 
    some indented text some indented text some indented text 
some text some text some text 
some text some text some text
```

I can do it manually by inserting additional white-space characters. But it is not a LaTex style solution. I am looking for such a solution.

Comment: You can use `tabbing`, which is probably simplest in this setup. See [Starting a line where the previous line finishes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/110314/5764).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). You can just use the list environment and set the label to be empty. That was if the line gets longer it will wrap properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution using [the `enumitem` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem) where I had used an empty label, and set the `leftmargin` of the top level list as `0pt`:

[image]

### Notes:

- [The `showframe` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/showframe)
  was used just to show the page margins.
  It is not needed in your actual use case.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{showframe}
\newlist{MyIndentedList}{itemize}{4}
\setlist[MyIndentedList,1]{%
    label={},
    noitemsep,
    leftmargin=0pt,
    }
\setlist[MyIndentedList]{%
    label={},
    noitemsep,
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{MyIndentedList}
\item some text some text some text 
\item some text some text some text 
    \begin{MyIndentedList}
        \item some indented text some indented text some indented text 
        \item some indented text some indented text some indented text 
        \begin{MyIndentedList}
             \item some more indented text some more indented text  
             \item some more indented text some more indented text 
         \end{MyIndentedList} 
    \end{MyIndentedList}
\item some text some text some text 
\item some text some text some text 
    \begin{MyIndentedList}
        \item some indented text some indented text some indented text 
        \item some indented text some indented text some indented text 
        \begin{MyIndentedList}
             \item some more indented text some more indented text  
             \item some more indented text some more indented text  
         \end{MyIndentedList} 
        \item some indented text some indented text some indented text 
        \item some indented text some indented text some indented text 
     \end{MyIndentedList} 
\item some text some text some text 
\item some text some text some text 
\end{MyIndentedList}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know lists can be used in this way. :)

Comment: I got the error `! Undefined control sequence.`
`<recently read> \newlist `
                         
`l.4 \newlist`
`            {MyIndentedList}{itemize}{4}`
`? `

`! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.`

Comment: @TemPora You have an outdated TeX system; I can go back to TeX Live 2010 and `\newlist` exists in `enumitem`.

Comment: @egreg Thanks. I tried with latest Tex online and it worked.

Comment: 100k !!! sorry I missed it

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks. I miss the good old days when I was _almost_ keeping up with you on the rep. :-)

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments, you could use the `tabbing` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tabbing}
  \hspace{30pt}\=\hspace{30pt}\=\kill
  some text some text some text \\ 
  some text some text some text  \\ 
   \> some indented text some indented text some indented text \\ 
   \> some indented text some indented text some indented text \\
   \>  \> some more indented text some more indented text  \\ 
   \>  \> some more indented text some more indented text  \\
  some text some text some text \\ 
  some text some text some text  \\ 
   \> some indented text some indented text some indented text \\ 
   \> some indented text some indented text some indented text \\
   \>  \> some more indented text some more indented text  \\ 
   \>  \> some more indented text some more indented text  
 \end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```

Which then will look like this:

[image]

You can control the width of the tabs with the `\hspace`

Comment: It works (at least in beamer). What is the package behind this? Is it actually called `tabbing` package? When I add `\usepackage{tabbing}`, I get tabbing.sty not found error.

Comment: It's actually called `Tabbing` – I had the same issue and this helped. So it's `\usepackage{Tabbing}`