# How to align text with preceding lines and to create one-line, right-aligned dates in CV?

Tags: spacing

I am new to Tex and this is my first post, so any general comments about how I could improve my code or the formatting of this post (in addition to any specific answers for how I can solve the issue below) would be appreciated!

I am trying to create a CV (anonymised code presented below) in Overleaf and am having two issues:

1. Almost all of the dates are falling over the first line and don't show up neatly. How could I get them on one line, as the date in the 'Interests and positions of responsiblity' section manages to do? (I've had a look for posts regarding similar issues, but have only found material on CVs created using the `moderncv` package.)
2. In the 'Skills' section, the details about programming take up more than one line. This is fine, but I would like there to be an indent on the second line, so that the beginning of the second line on programming skills lines up with the beginning of the description of programming skills on the first line. How could I do this? (The closest post that I found was [how to align multiple lines on same indent without enumeration](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191677/how-to-align-multiple-lines-on-same-indent-without-enumeration), but I'm not sure if and how this could be applied in my case.)

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl} % KOMA-article class
```

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}     % Math packages
\usepackage{graphicx}                    % Enable pdflatex
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}            % Colors by their 'svgnames'
\usepackage{geometry}
    \textheight=700px                    % Saving trees ;-)
\usepackage{url}

\frenchspacing              % Better looking spacings after periods
\pagestyle{empty}           % No pagenumbers/headers/footers

%%% Custom sectioning (sectsty package)
%%% ------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{sectsty}

\sectionfont{%                      % Change font of \section command
    \usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n}%       % bch-b-n: CharterBT-Bold font
    \sectionrule{0pt}{0pt}{-5pt}{3pt}}

%%% Macros
%%% ------------------------------------------------------------
\newlength{\spacebox}
\settowidth{\spacebox}{8888888888}          % Box to align text
\newcommand{\sepspace}{\vspace*{1em}}       % Vertical space macro

\newcommand{\MyName}[1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191677/how-to-align-multiple-lines-on-same-indent-without-enumeration){ % Name
        \noindent \Huge \usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n} #1 
        \par\normalsize \normalfont}

\newcommand{\MyEmail}[1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191677/how-to-align-multiple-lines-on-same-indent-without-enumeration){ % Email (optional)
        \noindent \large \usefont{T1}{phv}{m}{n}  #1
        \par\normalsize \normalfont}

\newcommand{\MyMobile}[1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191677/how-to-align-multiple-lines-on-same-indent-without-enumeration){ % MyMobile (optional)
        \noindent \large \usefont{OT1}{phv}{m}{n}  #1
        \par\normalsize \normalfont}

\newcommand{\MyAddress}[1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191677/how-to-align-multiple-lines-on-same-indent-without-enumeration){ % MyAddress (optional)
        \noindent \large \usefont{OT1}{phv}{m}{n}  #1
        \par\normalsize \normalfont}

\newcommand{\NewPart}[1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191677/how-to-align-multiple-lines-on-same-indent-without-enumeration){\section*{\uppercase{#1}}}

\newcommand{\PersonalEntry}[2]{
        \noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 % Indentation
        \parbox{\spacebox}{        % Box to align text
        \textit{#1}}               % Entry name (birth, address, etc.)
        \hspace{1.5em} #2 \par}    % Entry value

\newcommand{\SkillsEntry}[2]{      % Same as \PersonalEntry
        \noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 % Indentation
        \parbox{\spacebox}{        % Box to align text
        \textit{#1}}               % Entry name (birth, address, etc.)
        \hspace{1.5em} #2 \par}    % Entry value

\newcommand{\EducationEntry}[4]{
        \noindent \textbf{#1} \hfill      % Study
        \colorbox{White}{%
            \parbox{6em}{%
            \hfill\color{Black}#2}} \par  % Duration
        \noindent \textit{#3} \par        % School
        \noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 \small #4 % Description
        \normalsize \par}

\newcommand{\WorkEntry}[4]{               % Same as \EducationEntry
        \noindent \textbf{#1} \hfill      % Jobname
        \colorbox{White}{\color{Black}#2} \par  % Duration
        \noindent \textit{#3} \par              % Company
        \noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 \small #4 % Description
        \normalsize \par}

\newcommand{\Responsibilities}[4]{                % Same as \EducationEntry
        \noindent \textbf{#1} \hfill      % Title
        \colorbox{White}{\color{Black}#2} \par  % Duration
        \noindent \textit{#3} \par              % Company
        \noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 \small #4 % Description
        \normalsize \par}

%%% Begin Document
%%% ------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\MyName{My name}
\MyAddress{My address}
\MyEmail{{My email}}

%%% Education
%%% ------------------------------------------------------------
\NewPart{Education}{}

\EducationEntry{Education}{Sep xxxx-Present}{My university}
               {\begin{itemize}
               \item Details
               \item Details 
               \end{itemize}}

\EducationEntry{More education}{Sep xxxx-Jun xxxx}{Institution}
               {\begin{itemize}
               \item Details
               \end{itemize}}

\EducationEntry{More education}{Sep xxxx-Jun xxxx}{Institution}
               {\begin{itemize}
               \item Details
               \end{itemize}}

%%% Work experience
%%% ------------------------------------------------------------
\NewPart{Work experience}{}

\EducationEntry{Role}{Aug xxxx-Aug xxxx}{Organisation}
               {\begin{itemize}
               \item Details

\item Details

           \item Details
           \end{itemize}}



\EducationEntry{Role}{Feb xxxx-Dec xxxx}{Organisation}
              {\begin{itemize}
               \item Details
              \end{itemize}
               }

%%% Responsibilities
%%% ------------------------------------------------------------
\NewPart{Interests and positions of responsibility}{}

\Responsibilities{Role}{Mar xxxx-Mar xxxx}{Organisation}
                 {\begin{itemize}
                 \item Details
                 \end{itemize}
                 }

%%% Skills
%%% ------------------------------------------------------------
\NewPart{Skills}{}

\SkillsEntry{Programming}{Some text regarding programming skills, that spans more than one line}
\SkillsEntry{Systems}{Details}
\SkillsEntry{Languages}{Details}

\flushleft\sepspace 

References available on request

\end{document}

Answer (score 1):

You can load the `eqparbox` package and replace the definition of `\EducationEntry` with

```
\newcommand{\EducationEntry}[4]{
        \noindent \textbf{#1} \hfill % Study
        \colorbox{White}{%
            \eqmakebox[duration][r]{%
            \color{Black}#2}} \par % Duration 
        \noindent \textit{#3} \par % School
        \noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 \small #4 % Description
        \normalsize \par}
```

For the hanging indent problem, use this:

```
\newcommand{\SkillsEntry}[2]{ % Same as \PersonalEntry
        \noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=-2% Indentation
        \parbox{\spacebox}{ % Box to align text
        \textit{#1}} % Entry name (birth, address, etc.)
        \hspace{1.5em} #2 \par} % Entry value
```

Last remark: in the code `\colorbox{White}{\color{Black}#2}`, `\color{Black}`  isn't needed, as `\colorbox{some colour}`  changes only the colour of the background.

[image]

Comment: That worked well. Do you have any idea how I could deal with the issue of the misaligned text under 'Programming' in the 'Skills' section?

Comment: @CKKOY: I've updated my answer. It is enough to replace `hangafter=0` with `hangafter=-2` (or even less if there are more lines).  B.t.w., is there any particular reason why, in  the definition of your commands, you load `helvetica` (`phv`) both with encoding `T1` and encoding `OT1`?